# Contact Form 7 WordPress Plugin with Apaches(htaccess) and php 7 - No route was found matching the URL and request method

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, contact-form-7

Accessing the https://EXAMPLE.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/5/feedback

I get an error:

```
{
"code":"rest_no_route",
"message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method",
"data":{"status":404}
}
```

When you submit the forms on the web page, it gets the ***409 Conflict Error***:

It seems the problem is solved by removing the **htaccess** declarations for **php** version like below:

**FROM**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**TO**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, how can we have **Both** PHP declaration and allow contact form 7 to use the **Rest Route** ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this solution works well for me.

You have to do the proper SMTP setting, If the default PHP Mailer is not working. 
 [image: SMTP PHP mailer]

1. Select Other SMTP 
   [image: Other SMTP].
2. Put your SMTP Hostname e.g.: example.com  
   [image: Host Name]
3. Select TLS server point 
    [image: TLS]
4. Put Your SMTP Username/Pass from Hosting Provider. [image: SMTP Username/pass]

You can get the Username and Pass from the Hosting provider. 
[image: Email Account] 
 
[image: SMTP Username/Pass Hosting]

Answer (score 0):

The Hosting Company Whitelisted my IP and it worked!!!!

If anyone meets such similar situations, it can cause you to do a lot of unnecessary changes and yet it's just a small problem...

I realized VPN made it work too, but it was temporary until it was whitelisted.